# Drawing a shape?

Tags: java, android, view, setcontentview

I have tried to draw a shape for a long time without an answer. I used setContentView(view) for that view. However, I have another setContentView:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//Buttons, Views from XML...
setContentView( mCustomDrawableView);//Custom Shape
```

Problem is, it only shows **ONE** view, the shape. The `Buttons` defined on `XML` are gone. Basically whichever `setContentView(view)` is called last is the only `View` who is drawed. I've also tried **many** other ways to draw the shape without an answer that **works**.

I have seen that multiple `setContentView` do overlap each other, but this is the only way that *partially* works. Any way to display both Views **or** another way to draw a shape and my `XML Views`?

**EDIT:**

My shape is made in java, not XML

**EDIT 2:**

Here is my `customShape` Class:

```
 public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;


        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        // If the color isn't set, the shape uses black as the default.
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
       mDrawable.setBounds(x,y,x+10,y+10);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: @CodingM You can add the canvas to a layout, and override `onDraw()` to edit it, that way you are just showing a layout, not a canvas.

Comment: @Jamie Corkhill I have used this in the past and for me it didint work. Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK ...  setContentView is something which takes a layout/view/whatever and the input defines the contents of the activity/fragment your are setting it to.

So of course your first call does the whole layout, and the second wipes that and sets the content to what you're sending to it.

The thing is to have your view and then add it to a layout. If you have any view in your initial setContentView xml named (+id) and defined (Layout x = getfromid(r.id.x) you can then add your view to that layout with x.addview(myview) or x.addview(CustomDrawableView(context)).

-edit for clarification-

An Activity/Fragment has a Layout which you set using setContentView. You do this once, normally. A Layout defines where Views are placed.

So, you setContentView(your.xml) in onCreate. If you have a programmatic View class, you can then do two things: add new YourView to a named and specified layout in your act/frag (using any layout defined in xml, passed to your frag/act in the xml passed in setContentView and then defined by Layout x = findViewById(R.id.idoflayoutinxmlinfield 'android:id="@+id/x") in code.

Then you can x.addview(new MyView(context)) or Myview z = new MyView(context) and x.addView(z);

-edit2-

When you get better, you can also just add your custom View to the original layout by adding it to the original xml definition.

-edit3-

Sigh. OK. Here it is:

In your activities java file:

```
RelativeLayout myRellayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    setContenView(your.xml)
    myRelLayout = findViewByID(R.id.myrellayout);
    myRelLayout.addView(new MyCustomView(this));
    //or define your custom view and the add it by:
    //MyCustomView mcv = new MyCustomView(this);
    //myRelLayout.addView(mcv);
}
```

And your xml should contain any layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/myrellayout"
    android:width="whatever"
    android:height="whatever"
    />
```

Comment: @MacD Do not accuse Jamie of downvoting you. The privilege of downvoting is granted at 125 rep. Furthermore I do not see any downvotes on your answer.